# How to create new email template in Admin end in magento 2

Tags: email-templates, magento2.2, admin-panel

**How to create a new email template in backend in magento 2**

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html 
Check this is official magneto 2 documentation about magneto 2 backend email template management.

Comment: GO to __Admin -> MARKETING -> Communications -> Email Templates__ and add new template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Admin panel, Click below path :

> Marketing -> Communication -> Email Templates

Click on **Add New Templates**, Get Your required template from Template dropdown at top of page. Click **Load Template** button.

Now, **Get Forgot Password** from dropdown & click on **load template** button.

Set Your Template name.

Template Content Textarea are auto fill up.

Now, you can change text as per your requirement.